# There is no such column error while fetching data from sqlite in Android

Tags: java, android

```
           Cursor m= a.getData("Akshay");
            StringBuffer sb= new StringBuffer();
            if(m!=null&&m.getCount()>0)
            {while (m.moveToNext())
            {
                sb.append(m.getString(m.getColumnIndex("Name")));


            }

                nametext.setText(sb.toString());

            }


       //Mydbhelper class//

       public Cursor getData(String ii) {


                SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

                Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from myTable where 
                 Email="+ii,null);

                return res;
      }
```

**//LOG**

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                               Process: com.example.user3.security, PID: 15620
>                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user3.security/com.example.user3.security.ProfileActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Akshay (code 1): , while compiling: select * from myTable where Email=Akshay
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2449)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2509)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:153)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5529)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
>                                                                                Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Akshay (code 1): , while compiling: select * from myTable where Email=Akshay
>                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
>                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
>                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
>                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
>                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
>                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
>                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1255)
>                                                                                   at com.example.user3.security.myDbHelper.getData(myDbHelper.java:101)
>                                                                                   at com.example.user3.security.ProfileActivity.onCreate(ProfileActivity.java:56)
>                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6303)
>                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2402)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2509) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:153) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373) 
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5529) 
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739) 
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629) 
>   11-27 12:01:24.886 15620-15620/com.example.user3.security E/MQSEventManagerDelegate: failed to get MQSService.

Comment: You had changed your table schema so just update database version in helper class constructor.

Comment: my database version is 2

Comment: so change it to 3. if problem persists then check that you are creating table with `Email` field. P.S.  may be you created field with `email` not `Email`

Comment: not worked yet bro

Comment: change your query to `....where 
             Email='"+ii+"'"`   String values should be in single quote in where clause

Answer (score 2):

Your query has an issue.  You are running the following literal query:

```
select * from myTable where Email = Akshay;
```

If you read the error message closely, you will see complaints about not being able to find the column "Akshay" which of course was not intended to be a column, but rather a string literal in the final query.

The fix here is to bind the string literal in your query correctly.  Consider the following refactor of `getData()`:

```
public Cursor getData(String ii) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from myTable where Email = ?",
        new String[] { ii }
    );

    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with your SQL query. The current query is looking for another column named "Akshay". You need to modify your code so that your query has leading and trailing single quote with the parameter value.

```
Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from myTable where 
             Email='"+ii+"'",null);
```